# How do you use the MySQL replication driver in Grails (on Tomcat)?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, grails, replication

I have a Grails (2.2.1) app for which I'm trying to configure MySQL replication. These settings work fine via "grails run-app" but fail when run via Tomcat:

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = "jdbc:mysql:replication://app1-db.cykm5cykm5.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com,app1-db-rr1.cykm5cykm5.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/app1_production?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver"

    username = "Username"
    password = "Password"

    properties {
        defaultReadOnly = false
        initialSize = 10
        maxActive = 110
        maxIdle = 60
        minIdle = 10
        maxWait = 10000
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Must specify at least one slave host to connect to for master/slave replication load-balancing functionality
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connectReplicationConnection(NonRegisteringDriver.java:393)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringReplicationDriver.connect(NonRegisteringReplicationDriver.java:52)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 8 more
```

Any idea why I'd see this exception, and why it doesn't appear when running the grails dev server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the actual `url` with IPs/domains of master and slave? And why do we need `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` in the URL?

Comment: Updated with something closer to actual URL. I did test the identical connection string in both places with the same result - works with "run-app" but not with Tomcat. And the extra params are just a convenient way to configure the connection to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with having a second data source defined. The replication driver was being loaded for both data sources, even though the second data source had a non-replication connect string.

Configuring the second data source with a replication-friendly connect string resolved the issue.